# How to split data variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to split value stored in `data.address`. I `alert(data.address)` and it showed me Maharashtra,mumbai I want to split them into two parts and place in input fields.I tried `async:false,` but didnt work , then I tried `(data.address).val().split(',');` but it shows Undefined

Here is my Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#phone').focusout(function() {
    var user = $(this).val();
    //alert(user);
    $.ajax({
      url: "ph_search.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      data: {
        user: user
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data.address);
        var add = data.address;
        var result = add.split(',');
        //alert(result[2]);
        $('#phone').val(data.phone);
        $('#email').val(data.email);
        $('#add').val(data.address);
        $('#cust_id').val(data.id);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `var add = add.address.split(",")` will give you an array - if you know it's in 2 parts, you can access them with `add[0]` and `add[1]` giving `$("#add").val(add[0])`

Comment: You should not need to use async and it has certainly nothing to do with a split.
`data.address.split(",") ` should work. Try to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.address))` to see if there are weird characters in the string. For example if address is `["Maharashtra","Mumbai"]` then it is not a string but an array already and a toString() of an array will add a comma

Comment: result[2] is going to be undefined since there are only 2 items in the array. Arrays start at index ZERO not ONE.

Comment: @epascarello exactly, silly mistake of mine . Its

Answer (score 1):

Array index start from 0.

If you split the string "Maharashtra,mumbai" you get ["Maharashtra","mumbai"];

```
var splitted = "Maharashtra,mumbai".split(",");
console.log(splitted[0]); /// Maharashtra
console.log(splitted[1]); /// mumbai
console.log(splitted[2]); /// undefined
```

There is no element with index = 2 in your array.